# Model Targets and Data Security

Tags: model, target, vuforia

I'm looking at the use of Vuforia Model Targets. As far as I am aware, to create a new model target from CAD, you need to upload your model to Vuforia servers for processing. Is that right? Or is it possible to use Vuforia tools running locally to do that job?

Thanks for any pointers,
Dave

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It depends on the type of Model Target you plan to create.

"Regular" Model Targets **do not** upload the 3D model to the Cloud. [Advanced Model Targets](https://library.vuforia.com/model-targets/advanced-model-target-databases) upload select data from the 3D model to the Cloud for training, which is subsequently deleted after training is complete.

Please find this detailed article on [Vuforia Engine Data Security](https://library.vuforia.com/faqs/vuforia-engine-data-security). This is relatively new to our library, so if you have any feedback let us know.